# How can I filter out consecutive repeats in a sequence?

Tags: sequence, raku

I'm trying to generate a `Seq` of random options where consecutive repeats are not allowed:

```perl6
> (<F R U>.roll(*).grep(* ne *))[^10]
((R F) (F U) (R F) (F R) (U R) (R F) (R F) (U F) (R U) (U R))
```

Why does using `grep` in this way result in nested pairs? And how can I achieve what I'm looking for? Using `.flat` above will still allow consecutive repeats.

```perl6
( R U F U F U R F R U ... )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> how can I achieve what I'm looking for?

I believe the `squish` method will do what you want:

```
say <F R U>.roll(*).squish.head(20)
```

This produces:

```
(U R F U F R F R F U F R U R F U R U R F)
```

> Why does using grep in this way result in nested pairs?

Because `grep` (and `map` too) on something with an arity greater than 1 will work by breaking the list into chunks of that size. Thus given `A B C D`, the first call to the `grep` block gets `A B`, the second `C D`, and so on. What's really needed in this case, however, is a lagged value. One could use a `state` variable in the block passed to `grep` to achieve this, however for this problem `squish` is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could employ a simple regex using the `<same>` zero-width matcher. Below in the Raku REPL:

```
> my $a = (<F R U>.roll(*))[^20].comb(/\w/).join; say $a;
RRFUURFFFFRRFRFUFUUU

> say $/ if  $a ~~ m:g/ \w <!same> /;
(｢R｣ ｢F｣ ｢U｣ ｢R｣ ｢F｣ ｢R｣ ｢F｣ ｢R｣ ｢F｣ ｢U｣ ｢F｣ ｢U｣)
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Predefined_Regexes